# Return corner coordinates of images after OpenDroneMap processing

Tags: python, gps, coordinates, opendronemap

I have images (with EXIF metadata) made by a drone relative to a particular place; having processed them with OpenDroneMap at this point I have an orthophoto with all the geolocated pixels.
At this point I was wondering if through Python and given the output of OpenDroneMap (GeoTIFF or other), it was possible to trace the coordinates of the angles of the individual photos used for the creation of this output.
Is it possible?